# Why am I not able to upload images with my question and other formating which are there in other stackexchange sites like latex

Tags: support

I am not able to include(upload) images while asking questions why is this?

Comment: Does the "image" button above the text box not work, or is it not showing up at all?

Comment: I was able to upload an image for both a question and answer logged in as myself and anonymously.

Answer (score 1):

1. Latex support shouldn't be required here, should it?
2. To upload images, click the image toolbar button on the toolbar or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>